# Base address requirement for NDEF messages on Type-5 tags?

Tags: nfc, ndef

I am trying to program an NDEF-URL into a Type-5 NFC tag. When I program this message into block zero of the tag, my android phone can read it just fine and successfully redirects to the URL www.abc.com:
[Picture of NDEF URL Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtBNc.png)

```
block 00 - E1 40 40 00
block 01 - 03 0C D1 01
block 02 - 08 55 01 61
block 03 - 62 63 2E 63
block 04 - 6F 6D FE FF
```

However, if I erase the tag, and reprogram the message to start at block-1, it will not work.

My application already works with tags which have information up to block-10, and I am likely unable to change the mapping. I was hoping to add an NDEF record to this tag starting at a non-zero block.

Is there anyway that the message needs to be reformatted to use a different starting block or is it a requirement that the message start at block zero of the tag (and where is this requirement documented, I cannot find it anywhere).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With reference to T5T tag, Block 0 stores the Capability Container value.
The Structure of CC is shown in the image [image: T5T Capability Container]

The Capability Container (CC) manages the information of the NFC Forum Type 5 Tag.
There are two ways CC can be configured: 4byte CC or 8byte CC

The four bytes CC limits the maximum Data area size at 2040 bytes (block number is coded on one byte, "MLEN" with reference to image).

When extended to eight bytes, the CC allows a larger Data area (block number is coded on two bytes). 4byte CC consumes Block0 location and 8byte CC consumes Block0 and Block1 of memory.

With reference to the image, I've taken an example value for 4byte CC as E1 40 20 00, where 20 is the MLEN i.e. message length.

It is the CC value based on whose value any reader detects NDEF. So, whenever you wish to write any NDEF message, you first have to write CC.

For your NDEF to get detected, replace the MLEN value i.e. 20h with your NDEF message length and write it to block 0( E1 40 [NDEF LEN] 00). From block 1, write the NDEF message.

NOTE: NDEF Message must start from the end of CC, i.e. there should not be any gap or empty bytes between CC and NDEF message.

Cheers!